# Objective C - Convert DateTime to Local DateTime

Tags: objective-c, datetime, converters

I am pretty new to Objective C and it has been horrible experience to get the current device datetime in systemTimeZone. This is what I have:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *DateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[DateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
[DateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"];
NSString *currentDateTime = [DateFormatter stringFromDate:now];
NSDate *curDate = [DateFormatter dateFromString:currentDateTime];
```

Line 5 NSString has the correct local datetime in currentDateTime string variable. But Line 6 again switches back to UTC DateTime. I do not understand why it would switch back to UTC even though the DateFormatter has the systemTimezone set. Can you please help me find out what is that I am missing?

Comment: Line 1 is all you need. Lines 2-5 are only needed when you wish to display the time to the user (but use date and time styles, not a date format). Line 6 is unnecessary.

Comment: The reason is because your date format doesn't include the timezone. When you convert it to a string, you're essentially stripping off the timezone, and when it's reinterpreted it assumes GMT. Either set the timezone explicitly to GMT or expand your string format (`"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm ZZZZ"`). See [NSDateFormatter and Internet Dates](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1480/_index.html)

Comment: @JamesBucanek Incorrect. The assumed timezone when converting the string (without its own timezone) is the timezone set on the date formatter. In this case it is the user's current timezone. GMT is not assumed anywhere. There is absolutely nothing wrong with the code in the question other than being unnecessary. The real issue is the OP's misunderstanding of the output shown when logging an instance of `NSDate`.

Comment: All I need is a NSDate type with current locale date time instead of UTC date time.

Comment: @user2980765 The very first line of code in your question does that. It's all you need.

Comment: @rmaddy the very first line gets me the UTC date time and not the current locale date time.

Comment: @user2980765 Sorry but you are incorrect. The first line gets the current time. Period. There is no timezone in an `NSDate`. Don't get confused when logging an `NSDate`. That shows the value formatted for the UTC timezone. That's just how it is displayed. Don't worry about timezones until try to display the date to the user using an NSDateFormatter.

Comment: @rmaddy I do not understand this. What you mean the first line gets the current time? The first line gets device current time + 7 hours and it it not the current time per the user. Period. The issue with NSDateFormatter is it gives the converted time in string and not as NSDate.

Comment: Yes, the first line is the current time. As I've said several times already, your confusion is being caused by your misunderstanding of the output of printing or logging an `NSDate` value. Just use the first line as is. Move on with whatever you need to do with the date.

Comment: @user2980765 Please see http://www.maddysoft.com/articles/dates.html for an article that may help clear things up for you.

Answer (score -1):

Just set the timeZone in the dateFormatter, This code is enough

```
NSString *dateString = @"24 08 2011 09:45PM";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MM yyyy hh:mma"];
NSTimeZone* sourceTimeZone = [NSTimeZone  timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"BST"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:sourceTimeZone];

NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

The dateFromString will now have the date 24 08 2011 08:45PM(GMT).. Then to convert this to string with local time just code the following,

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MM yyyy hh:mma"];
NSString *stringFromDAte = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateString];
```

**or** You can also try this one:

```
NSTimeInterval seconds; // assume this exists
NSDate* ts_utc = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:seconds];

NSDateFormatter* df_utc = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[df_utc setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];

   [df_utc setDateFormat:@"yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss zzz"];

    NSDateFormatter* df_local = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
   [df_local setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"EST"]];


   [df_local setDateFormat:@"yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss zzz"];

NSString* ts_utc_string = [df_utc stringFromDate:ts_utc];
NSString* ts_local_string = [df_local stringFromDate:ts_utc];

 // you can also use NSDateFormatter dateFromString to go the opposite way
```

Table of formatting string parameters:

https://waracle.com/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/

If performance is a priority, you may want to consider using strftime

https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/strftime.3.html

Comment: Thanks. I do not want a string at the end. I need NSDate with current locale date time instead of UTC.

Comment: You have apply minor changes on the code. After that you will achieve the functionality. I can't give you exactly code.